# add long to DateTime

Tags: android, jodatime

In my programm the user can add any value to a given DateTime in seconds, hours, days, months, weeks or years and the programm calculates the new date.

For example the user can add 1.000.000 weeks to his birthday and he'll get the DateTime when he is exactly 1.000.000 weeks old.

The DateTime-object has some nice methods for this issue like `plusSeconds` or `plusHours`. Unfortunately those methods only except an `int` value.

To allow my users to add greater numbers I'd like to use a `long` value.

I could convert the user input in milliseconds and use the [plus](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus%28long%29)-method which expects a `long` value in milliseconds but then the date-calculation will get inaccurate.

Is there any way that I can add a `long` value for days or months etc. that will still be accurate?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the age of the universe is 10^18 seconds. That translates roughly to 2^60 seconds.

Comment: In other words, practically you would not overflow the integer limit if you are calculating sensible ages :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write method(s) to incrementally add days/months by splitting the given long value to multiples of int max values plus a remainder.

Ex:

```
private void addMonths(DateTime dateTime, long months) {
    int count = months / int.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {            
        dateTime.plusMonths(int.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    dateTime.plusMonths(months % int.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: I've thought about this, too. But this does not seem to be a very elegant way to do this.